# Google Calendar change a event date of one of the event in series without affecting other events using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

[image]

I have a recurring event that repeats every Monday, Unfortunately the 15th day event I had to reschedule on Thursday. So it looks like above. I tried with the below code and it caused all my old events to vanish. How to I code to make a certain event in the series to deviate from schedule? I am open to using Calendar API or Calendar service.

```
calendar.getEventById(eventId.replace("@google.com", "")).setTime(new Date("2021-03-18"), new Date("2021-03-18"));
```

But my code deleted all my March 1 and March 8 events. How do I make them as shown in Image1 preserving March 1 and March 8 event?

[image: This is incorrect as I lost all my March 1 and March 8 events]

Answer (score 0):

What you need to to is to access a specific instance of a given recurring event and update that event.

---

### [Accessing instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#accessing_instances)

To see all the [instances](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#instances_and_exceptions) of a given recurring event you can use the [events.instances()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances) request.

The [events.list()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) request by default only returns single events, recurring events, and [exceptions](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#instances_and_exceptions); instances that are not exceptions are not returned. If the [singleEvents](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#singleEvents) parameter is set then all the individual instances do appear in the result, but not the underlying recurring events.

Individual instances are similar to single events. Unlike their parent recurring events, instances do not have the [recurrence](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#recurrence) field set.

**The following event fields are specific to instances:**

- [recurringEventId](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#recurringEventId) — the ID of the parent recurring event this instance belongs to
- [originalStartTime](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#originalStartTime) — the time this instance starts according to the recurrence data in the parent recurring event. This can be different from the actual [start](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#start) time if the instance was rescheduled. It uniquely identifies the instance within the recurring event series even if the instance was moved.

---

### **Sample Code:**

```
  var eventInstances = Calendar.Events.instances(calendarId,eventId).items;
  Logger.log(eventInstances);

  if(eventInstances!=null){
    for (var i=0; i<eventInstances.length; i++){
      if(eventInstances[i].originalStartTime.date == "2021-03-15"){
        Logger.log("EVENT FOUND, instance id: "+eventInstances[i].id);
        CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId).getEventById(eventInstances[i].id).setTime(new Date("2021-03-18"), new Date("2021-03-18"));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

**What it does?**

1. Assuming you already have the event Id for the recurring event, you just need to use [events.instances()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances) to get its event instances.
2. Check each instances based on your desired condition (In this example, I looked for an instance with the `originalStartTime.date` of `"2021-03-15"` and get its unique event id.
3. Use that event id to update a particular instance using [CalendarEvent.setTime(startTime, endTime)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#settimestarttime,-endtime)

---

### OUTPUT:

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

---

### **Note:**

I hope you won't get confused between the event id available from [events.list()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) and [events.instances()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances) requests.

[events.list()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)

- will give you the event id of the event series (example: `2u0bbeqqitlqr99m88u35sxxxx`)

[events.instances()](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances)

- will give you the event id of each instances within the event series (example instance: `2u0bbeqqitlqr99m88u35sxxxx_20210315`)